# Copying and pasting logarithmic trend line equation from chart into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste a log trend line from a chart into a cell. A sample equation is as follows: y = 0.0083ln(x) - 0.0902. As I run the regression for different datapoints, the equation constantly changes. Hence, I'd like the macro to copy and paste the equation into a cell. The following code does not work when the equation changes (i.e., it does the very first time, but after that, I get an error). The code is as follows:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C35").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Excel shows that the error is on "ActiveSheet.Paste". I would really appreciate some guidance on how to resolve the issue.

Thanks!
[QHARR - reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCAdf.png)

Comment: can you have a button push to collect latest equation or is it supposed to respond to your running the regression? Can you share some data (2 regressions?) and expected outcomes? Where would result go? How is regression being run?

Comment: Hi QHarr! The regressions are quite similar in nature e.g., y = 0.3ln(x) - 0.8252 and y = 0.023234ln(x) - 0.021. My ultimate aim is to get the slope (0.3 and 0.02324) and intercept (-0.8252 and -0.023234) into cells and use for further extrapolation based on different values of x.  Once equation is pasted onto a cell (e.g., C35), I plan on using: =MID(C35,SEARCH("= ",C35)+2,SEARCH("ln(x)",C35)-SEARCH("= ",C35)-2) to

Comment: get the slope value and =RIGHT(C35,LEN(C35)-FIND(")",C35)) to get the intercept value. I realize its possible to use the LINEST formula to get these values but the problem I ran into is that some of my datapoints are (0, #NA) and such datapoints will remain throughout the project. Despite this, the chart is able to give me a logarithmic equation but when I use LINEST, I get #VALUE! errors.

Comment: Re: button push - that is fair game!

Comment: Sample data and expected output? (small sample) Can you include an image?

Comment: can you use a helper column like https://ufile.io/pbskb xlsx

Comment: Hello QHarr, added picture added onto original post. Thanks!

Comment: obviously extend helper columns for x matrix. It is basically swopping out error values. I was already doing this and then saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622773/missing-values-in-ms-excel-linest-trend-logest-and-growth-functions

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concept of helper columns for x matrix - could you please briefly describe how it applies?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `.DataLabel.Formula` or `.DataLabel.Text` to write out the formula using VBA. I also give an in sheet method for completeness.

The advantage below is to show you how to start checking the trend type is the one you want and serves as the basis for expanding to loop over other series if needed.

Updating -

1) Use a Worksheet_Change Event:

You could tie this to a [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event where the target is your Y range, but set it so is only triggered once per update

2) You could tie to the execution of the macro to a control.

E.g. a command button from the forms control is simpliest. Ribbon > developer tab > controls > [form controls](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283). Generally, less problematic than ActiveX objects. Then associate that command button with the macro `GetTrendlineEquation` (right click button and associate should do it). Then pushing the button will execute the macro.

If you really want to be sure you are getting the right equation, or to get multiple you could iterate over charts, chartseries and trendlines.

After the main code I include an example of checking that the target series trend type is Logarithmic.

Code version which writes out the equation to the next available row in column A of worksheet 1.

```
Public Sub GetTrendLineEquation()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as appropriate

    Dim targetChart As Chart

    Set targetChart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart ' change as required

    Dim targetTrend As Trendline

    Set targetTrend = targetChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1) ' change as appropriate

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim nextRow As Long

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUP).Row

    If lastRow = 1 Then 
        nextRow = 1 
    Else 
       nextRow = lastRow + 1
    End If

    ws.Range("A"& nextRow) = targetTrend.DataLabel.Formula

End Sub
```

Checking the trend type:

```
For Each targetTrend In myChart.SeriesCollection(1).TrendLines

    If targetTrend.Type = -4133 Then Msgbox "Log"

    ' If Left$(targetTrend.Name,3) = "Log" Then Msgbox "Log"

Next targetTrend
```

The enumerations for trend type can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xltrendlinetype-enumeration-excel), or via the object browser through members of the class `XLTrendlineType`.

Loop multiple series getting the trend formulas:

```
Dim currentSeries As Long

For currentSeries = 1 To myChartSeriesCollection.Count

    For Each targetTrend In myChart.SeriesCollection(1).TrendLines

        If targetTrend.Type = -4133 Then Debug.Print targetTrend.DataLabel.Text

    Next targetTrend  

Next currentSeries
```

**Formulas in a sheet:**

I had already used a helper column before I saw [Missing values in MS Excel LINEST, TREND, LOGEST and GROWTH functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622773/missing-values-in-ms-excel-linest-trend-logest-and-growth-functions)

The formula I used for in the helper column was:

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(D10),ISBLANK(D10)),0,1)
```

This looks at your Y values and returns 0 if #N/A or blank else 1. Then you multiply the original Y values by this so you have a new fully populated Y series that LINEST can plot.

Using a template from [@satesh](https://app.box.com/v/LCDing/file/2984443507) I got the slope and intercept calculations and plugged the whole thing into a concatencated string, which shows the formula  in a cell, as follows:

[image: Chart and formulas]

Rather simplistic but can the same principles be applied to your data?

Comment: Hi QHarr! Thanks once again for helping out. I tried using the formula method shown in your comment above. The problem I run into is that the moment I input a 0 Y value as part of the dataset, the formula immediately goes to #VALUE!. This is probably due to the fact that we're using a LOG plot. Interestingly enough, the equation on the chart remains the same (and accurate) irrelevant of whether the Y value is an =NA() or not. I don't understand the subtitles between differences between the way the chart calculates regression equations vs the formulas, but if there was a way in the

Comment: formula approach to simply ignore or skip a Y value when #NA shows up (i.e., not plot it at all since e.g., (0,0) if it were possible to plot, would skew the dataset and hence the regression) that would solve the issue

Comment: That was what I was exploring with the spreadsheet option earlier. The simplest immediate answer was my code saying use the .Formula or .Text but what I was interested in exploring was could I work out how the missing or n/a's were being handled internally by playing with the input on the right and checking against the chart.

Comment: But where did you put the zero? Did you look at the workbook I shared? If you put 0 in column C the plot remains. I think maybe it is because I don't understand either your process or data layout properly?

Comment: Yes I did look at the workbook. And yes, you're right - the plot remains unchanged when a 0 is put in column C. Its the formula INDEX(LINEST(...) that results in #VALUE! when 0 is inserted into column C. And as a result, I'm unable to extrapolate values based the regression because the equation is not in a cell.

Comment: Formula in cell G16

Comment: Done! You've been super helpful!

Comment: Lol my bad. Let me change that. Btw, any work around the NA() values for the formulas?

Comment: Did you receive upvote? Seems like I can't do it just yet because I don't have 15 reputations just yet

Answer (score 0):

use `Text` property of `DataLabel` object

```
Range("C35").Value = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
```